# Running a Python script from the Python Shell

Tags: python

I wrote a script and saved it as test.py (code shown below). And when I run it from the script (Run Module 5), I get the result in the Python Shell.

But I have tried multiple suggestions available online to have it run from the Python Shell instead to which I fail (one error pasted below).

How can I run a python script from the python shell? 
The version of Python I am running is 3.7.3 and in Windows.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

print(" Hello, world!")

exec(open(test.py).read())
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    exec(open(test.py).read())
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

Comment: Don't use `exec()` ever. Just remove that line from your file.

Comment: Just do „import test“.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Use back ticks around code in comments.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Many mobile keyboards don’t do them ´properly´.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Gotchya! My android keyboard has a backtick key, but it took quite a while for me to find it. I'm sure that it is even more difficult for keyboard apps outside of the U.S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the last line for it to run. All you need is:

```
!/usr/bin/python3

print(" Hello, world!")
```

If you want to run it from another file, don't use exec. Instead, import it.

```
import test
```

Comment: I did. And it worked. Is it completely legitimate ? As I thought, import is for modules ? Does it work to import scripts in a python shell  ? Thanks.

Comment: It is definitely more legitimate than using exec on another file. Import can be used to run modules or packages. A module is basically just a python script, so yes, it does work to import python scripts.

Comment: Or, let me put it this way -- what's the most legitimate way of doing this -- if there is anything like this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the "test.py" as a string (use quotes).
test is not a known object.

Comment: While this might work (depending on the current working directory), it is better to remove the `exec()` call entirely.